# Eliminating the last comma from json records for iOS NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

This is my code in app.js

```
app.get('/all_question', function(req, res){


    var listQuestion = function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);
            res.render('all_question.html', { layout : false , 'title' : 'Question Bank', 'results' : results });
        });
    }

    var Client = new Db('questionbank', new Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {}));
    Client.open(function(err, pClient) {
        Client.collection('questions', listQuestion);
        //Client.close();
    });

})
```

This is what I'm calling as all_questions.html:

```
{"questions":[{{#each results}}{"id":"{{this._id}}","subject":"{{this.subject}}","qType":"{{this.qType}}","score":"{{this.score}}","question":{"name":"{{this.question.name}}","choice":["{{this.question.choice}}"],"answer":["{{this.question.answer}}"]}}{{/each}},]}`
```

This is the result:

```
{"questions":[{"id":"50d2de8879f86d9663000002","subject":"General","qType":"1","score":"1","question":{"name":"Earth is the center of the Universe","choice":["False,True"],"answer":["1"]}}{"id":"50d2e29e79f86d9663000003","subject":"General","qType":"2","score":"1","question":{"name":"Which is the biggest continent","choice":["Australia,Asia,Africa"],"answer":["2"]}},]}
```

Since there needs to be a comma to separate each record I output a comma at the end of each record. But it is also applied to the last record.  But when I use this as a webservice call inside iOS to input to NSDictionary, I'm getting an error due the comma at the last record.  How do i eliminate this?

Comment: First Calculate the no of elements in the array.The Put a if else Condition if the current element is Last Element then don't use ","

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(source.length - 3, 3)];
```